# Regexp extract items as multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, regex

I am not sure how to do this, but I am trying to get the expressions from each `if/elseif` line.

I am able to somewhat extract them using these two lines:

```
var ifreg = /\{if\s+?(.+?)\}([\s\S]+?)\{else/ig.exec(block);
var elseifreg = /\{elseif\s+?(.+?)\}([\s\S]+?)\{else/ig.exec(block);
```

but the results are not pretty looking (second exp):

```
[ '{elseif 2 == 2}\n            Two is equal to two\n        {else',
'2 == 2',
'\n            Two is equal to two\n        ',
index: 52,
input: '{if 1 == 2}\n            One is equal to two\n        {elseif 2 == 2}\n            Two is equal to two\n        {elseif 4 != 5}\n            Four does not equal five\n        {else}\n            Something went wrong...\n        {/if}' ]
```

Here is the teplate I am searching:

```
{if 1 == 2}
    {foreach $row in $items}
        I am here
    {/foreach}
{elseif $item == 2}
     {$item} is equal to two
{elseif 4 != 5}
     Four does not equal five
{else}
    Something went wrong...
{/if}
```

What I would like to accomplish, is to get all the results using one expression, and get the results to look something like this (doesn't have to be exactly the same but close):

```
[
    ['1 == 2', '{foreach $row in $items}
        I am here
    {/foreach}'],
    ['$item == 2', '{$item} is equal to two'],
    ['4 != 5', 'Four does not equal five'],
    ['Something went wrong...']
]
```

What can I do to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuing **str** is your string. `newlines` are optional

```
var results = []
str.match(/\{[^{}]+/g).forEach(function(a,b) {
    results[b]=[a.replace(/(?:if|else|elseif|\/if|\{)\s?/g, '')];
    results[b][0]===''&&results[b].splice(0,1);
});
str.match(/[^{}]+\{/g).forEach(function(a,b) {
    results[b].push(a.substring(0,a.length-1).trim());
});
results.pop();
```

The value of `results` is:

```
[
    [
        "1 == 2",
        "One is equal to two"
    ],
    [
        "2 == 2",
        "Two is equal to two"
    ],
    [
        "4 != 5",
        "Four does not equal five"
    ],
    [
        "Something went wrong..."
    ]
]
```

Comment: is it possible to not require newlines?

Comment: so, I tried adding a tag within the tag, is it hard parsing it like in my updated question?

Comment: @TheBoogieMan Ah, it only works with ifs but you can update `/(?:if|else|elseif|\/if|\{)\s?/g` to work with your needs. I'll update my answer to work a bit better

Answer (score 1):

It isn't just a regex but I'd try something like this:

```
  var block='{if 1 == 2}\n            One is equal to two\n        {elseif 2 == 2}\n            Two is equal to two\n        {elseif 4 != 5}\n            Four does not equal five\n        {else}\n            Something went wrong...\n        {/if}';
var reg=/\{(?:else|(?:else)?if\s+(.+)*)\}\s*([^{]+)[\s]*\n/igm

var results = []
for (var result = reg.exec(block); result != null; result = reg.exec(block))
{
    var innerResult=[]
    if (result!=null && result.length > 1 && result[1]!=undefined) innerResult.push(result[1]);
    if (result!=null && result.length > 2 && result[2]!=undefined) innerResult.push(result[2]);
    if (innerResult.length>0) results.push(innerResult);
}
```